# CSS get rid of blue outline in textareas/selects when focused

Tags: html, css

I already know how to get rid of text input outlines with

```
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

but it doesn't work with textareas and selects. Thanks

EDIT: Already tried textarea:focus and select:focus, which don't work.

Comment: `inputs` are one tag, `textarea` another, its not the same thing.. I guess you need to reset this too -> `textarea:focus { outline: none; }` :)

Comment: before removing it do you know why elements get outlined when focused? Not all people can use mouses because of dissabilitys, so all webpages should be able to get viewed with only **tabing** trough them.

Answer (score 1):

no need for `:focus` you can simply do that by

```
input[type="text"], textarea, select {outline:none}
```

here is the working demo [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/kashiflatif90/6gtebyg5/)

Answer (score 0):

The `:focus` isn't required. Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea placeholder="without class"></textarea>
```

**CSS:**

```
textarea {
  outline: none;
}
```

**[Without class Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/muueqj7n/)**

But if you can set a class, much better.

**HTML:**

```
<textarea  class="no-focus" placeholder="Look ma, no focus!"></textarea>

<select class="no-focus">
  <option value="">Option, no focus!</option>
  <option value="">Option, no focus!</option>
  <option value="">Option, no focus!</option>
</select>


<textarea class="focus" placeholder="Your amazing textarea with focus"></textarea>
<select class="focus">
  <option value="">Option, with focus</option>
  <option value="">Option, with focus</option>
  <option value="">Option, with focus</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
.no-focus {
  outline: none;
}
.focus {
  outline-color: yellow;
}
/* Just for demo */
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
select {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

**[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2a53h75o/2/)**